# How can I run Nuget PowerShell cmdlet Install-Package in normal PowerShell session (not inside Visual Studio)?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, installation, nuget, nuget-package

I want to do some automation stuff and one of the steps is to install a Nuget package for **a Visual Studio C# project**. In Visual Studio, I can run the command `Install-Package JetBrains.Annotations` in the *Package Manager Console* panel. However, the same command doesn't work in a normal PowerShell session. How can I install a package for **a Visual Studio C# project** in a normal PowerShell session?

Comment: duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912572/how-to-run-nuget-package-manager-host-in-cmd-powershell

Comment: Maybe what you want is something like:[How How do I install the Nuget provider for PowerShell on a unconnected machine so I can install a nuget package from the PS command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273109/how-to-use-a-nuget-package-within-a-powershell-script) and [Powershell Install Nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519123/powershell-install-nuget-package) . After you install and register the provider, a simple command like `install-package xxx -source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2` can install corresponding package for you. (Run as admin I suggest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with `*-Package` cmdlets. I've done some automation stuff with NuGet, where I had to choose between NuGet CLI or PowerShell `*-Package` cmdlets. Since `nuget list --allversion` doesn't work since Feb 2017 (see [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4537)). I decided to use the PowerShell cmdlets.

From [PowerShell docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PackageManagement/Install-Package?view=powershell-5.0#examples):

```
PS> Install-Package -Name NuGet.Core -Source MyNuGet -Credential Contoso\TestUser
```

You may have to define the provider name to `NuGet` via `-ProviderName`:

> Specifies one or more package provider names to which to scope your package search. You can get package provider names by running the Get-PackageProvider cmdlet.
>
> ...
>
> Accepted values:  msi, Programs, msu, Bootstrap, PSModule, nuget, chocolatey

Reason why I wrote this answer though this question is marked as duplicate:

The [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912572/how-to-run-nuget-package-manager-host-in-cmd-powershell) answer marking this question as duplicate, refers to either use Visual Studios built in management console (which is implemented as seperate Powershell host, and therefore not useable via the standard PowerShell) or via the NuGet CLI tools (which didn't cover all my automation requirements). Using "*-Package` cmdlets are not covered by this answer.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is an example how to install `log4Net` NuGet package:

```
  Install-Package log4net -ProviderName NuGet -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

The get more information what is installed in the background you can attach the `-Verbose` switch.

As far as I can remember you've to use the `v2` API of NuGet.

Comment: Hi @Moerwald, I successfully installed NuGet.Core. But I have no idea how can I use it to install a package. Could you give an example please?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm trying it. Just to confirm, the command `Install-Package log4net...` installs log4net for the Visual Studio project in the current working directory and not just install it on the computer, right?

Comment: Per default it installs the package under `~\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\log4net.2.0.8\log4net.2.0.8.nupkg`, but the cmldet has a `-Destination` parameter, try this one.

Comment: You can also try a mixup with Powershell and Cake (https://cakebuild.net/), where you do the visual studio stuff via cake, and call cakes build.ps1 from Powershell.

Comment: Assuming NuGet.Core is the package from nuget.org, it's version 2.14.0, which is from Visual Studio 2013, which is why it doesn't support v3 feeds and will be missing any feature added in NuGet 3.x and later, such as support from NuGet packages using SemanticVersioning's `+build` metadata, so you won't be able to install/upgrade the latest version of many packages this way.